# Row Values in GRID field for a Submitted Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, urlfetch

[image: Grid Field]

we can only seem to get the column value for each row but not the row value.

So, in the grid field example we get an array as follows
(element 1) = OPPORTUNITY: OT Not Considered;
(element 2) = OPPORTUNITY: OT Considered

Is there a way we can also get the Row values?

Option 1 a second parallel array
(element 1) = OT 1;
(element 2) = OT 2

or Option 2
(element 1) = OT 1&&OPPORTUNITY: OT Not Considered;
(element 2) = OT 2&&OPPORTUNITY: OT Considered

Here's the GAS we're currently using to get the Form Submission

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var data = {
      "id": e.source.getId(),
   "OTC_user" : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      "title": e.source.getTitle() ? e.source.getTitle() : "Untitled Form",
      "is_private": e.source.requiresLogin(),
      "is_published": e.source.isAcceptingResponses(),
      "id": e.response.getId(),
      "timestamp": e.response.getTimestamp(),
      "fields": e.response.getItemResponses().map(function(y) {
    return {
        h: y.getItem().getTitle(),
        k: y.getResponse()
    }
      }, this).reduce(function(r, y) {
    r[y.h] = y.k;
    return r
      }, {})
 };

 var options = {
  method: "post",
  payload: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 };

 UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<WEBHOOK URL REMOVED", options);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Rows and columns of CheckboxGridItem cab be accessed.

*For CheckboxGridItem questions, this returns a String[][] array in which the answers at row index n corresponds to the question at row n + 1 in the checkbox grid. If a respondent did not answer a question in the grid, that answer is returned as ''.* ([GAS Class ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getResponse()))

This example is an edited example from [GAS Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response.html):

```
function doSomething() {

var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      Logger.log('Response #%s to the question (horizontal) "%s" was (vertical) "%s"',
          (i + 1).toString(),
          itemResponse.getItem().asCheckboxGridItem().getColumns(),
          itemResponse.getItem().asCheckboxGridItem().getRows());
    }
  }
/*
[20-02-15 17:30:18:028 CET] Response #1 to the question (horizontal) "[ja, neen, 
misschien]" was (vertical) "[aap, noot, mies]"
*/  
}
```